# Why do I get an intermittent msvc++ link error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Maybe 1 times out of 5, I get this error on a specific machine (incidentally, our buildbot) but it never occurs on my dev machine. I'm hoping that there's a hotfix for this from Microsoft, but I can't find one.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\synergy.lib'
```

It might be worth noting that this is using the 64-bit build tool, so I suppose that could be relevant. The machine is 32-bit, but I'm not sure if that's important. Please review the [full compile log](http://buildbot.synergy-plus.org:8000/builders/trunk-win64/builds/27/steps/compile/logs/stdio) for details.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you had a compile error in synergy project:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\include\xlocale(265) :
>   error C2039: '_DebugHeapTag_func' : is
>   not a member of 'std'

So **synergy.lib** was not built and hence the dependent projects could not find it. The reason why it happens on the build machine is that most likely it gets cleaned before a build, the lib file is never there unless it's built. On your dev machine even if there is an error, the output file is still there and the dependent project compiles.